# Tpl TaskCompletionSource on WP7 completes immediately

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, task-parallel-library

I am using Robert McLaws TPL library (http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks/3.0.1) on WP7 (Mango).

```
 var t1 = new TaskCompletionSource<int>().Task;
 var t2 = t1.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
 t1.Start();
```

"Hello" is printed to the debug console. But i have nowhere set the result on the TaskCompletionSource using SetResult or TrySetResult.

I was excepting the above code to never output "hello" as task t1 never finishes.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like it should throw at `t1.Start`. Maybe a TPL bug? Edit: Those are not Microsoft TPL tasks, aren't they?! So it has nothing to do with "the TPL". It is a 3rd party lib.

Comment: Have you seen: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983